# How to call AJAX on check-box of form API?

Tags: forms

**I need to get radio buttons in a form, whenever a checkbox gets enabled/clicked.**
Say, I have 5 items listed in a checkbox, named orange, apple, .....When I enable orange checkbox, a set of radio button comes that will ask color of the corresponding fruit. Any working example regarding this will be highlyy appreciated.

**EDIT**:

```
$form['toggle_me'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => t('Tick this box to type'),
   '#options' => array(0 => t('Orange'), 1 => t('Apple')),
);
$form['settings'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#states' => array(
    // Only show this field when the 'toggle_me' checkbox is enabled.
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="toggle_me"][#options][0]' => array(0 => t('red'), 1 => t('yellow')),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields module will help you to do this task

Comment: Thanks to understand my exact requirement. But I am looking to do it pro grammatically.

Comment: You may use '#states' attribute from Form API, more information you can find here
http://internetdevels.com/blog/drupal-states

Comment: I edit the code, can you please tell what's wrong with this. It's not working.I follow this[https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7] approach,

Comment: ':input[name="toggle_me[1]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)

Comment: @SugandhKhanna You can use simple jquery too if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, may be helpful for you

```
$form['checkbox'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Select',
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('Orange'), t('Apple'))),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'fruits_callback_form',
      'wrapper' => 'fruit-check',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
  $checkbox = !empty($form_state['values']['checkbox']) ? $form_state['values']['checkbox'] : 0;
  $form['slots']['#prefix'] = '<div id="fruit-check">';
  if ($checkbox == 'Orange') {
    $color = array(0 => t('Red'), 1 => t('Blue'));
  }
  $form['color'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Select Color'),
    '#options' => $color,
  );
  $form['slots']['#suffix'] = '</div>';


  //Callback function

  function fruits_callback_form($form, &$form_state) {
    return $form['color'];
  }
```

Comment: can I write radio form element in ajax callback function?Because I want radio buttons to get visible only if check-box gets enabled.

Comment: then use !empty($form_state['values']['checkbox']) in form.
If not empty then show your radio buttons.
Otherwise as you said, you can define in callback function also